# Store multidimensional array values into MySQL (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I have a large multidimensional array that I would like to store into a MySQL database.

Below is an example of the array in question:

```
Array
(
    [user1] =>
        [name] => abc
        ...
        [address] => xyz
    ...
    ...
    [user2] =>
        [name] => abc
        ...
        [address] => xyz
}
```

The array values and database table columns all match (apart from the rowid in the database). I have seen various methods of doing something similar, but haven't found a way that works in this solution.

Many thanks :)

**Update**

Updated the array structure to give a clearer idea whats in the array itself.

Comment: +1 for good question, title, and name "lethalMango".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I took the time to use a for loop and achieve the following:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 25; $i++)
    {
        $name = $parts[$i][0];
        $address = $parts[$i][22];

        // Run SQL query using the variable values rather than the array values.
    }
```

I'm sure there is a more sophisticated way of achieving this, but this worked for now!

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Usually when you've got nested data like this, it makes sense to have two tables.. one for parent and one for child, in order to most efficiently access the data.  The parent table would have "Parent ID" and whatever parent level data, and the child table would have "Child ID", a "Parent ID" foreign key, and child data (in your example, the three character string).

Comment: This is true 99% of the time, however, there may be a time when storing an array is valuable.

Comment: Sorry, I probably didnt explain it clear above. The nested data has been created by using array_chunk to get it all seperated correctly (into groups of 23). Each group needs to be inserted as a row into the database. The first dimention of the array [0] - [24] are just there to create groups.

Answer (score 0):

make a uni-dimensional array with serialized elements. You will insert one row only and each column will contain serialized arrays

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)? You can turn your array into a string, store it and then use  [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to turn it back.

[LIVE DEMO](http://codepad.org/ceB4feKZ)

Comment: This breaks the relational model.

Answer (score -1):

If you are needing to store the array itself, use [serialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [unserialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to store the array as a string within the database.  Much better than the json option Dutchie mentioned previously since json can have issues with multidimensional arrays.

Or are you wanting to store the values in the associated records in the db?

Answer (score -1):

If you're going to be storing arbitrarily deeply nested arrays, then either `json_encode()`/`json_decode()` or `serialize()`/`unserialize()` would be your best bets. The only issue is you'll be unable to query the data intuitively.

As already mentioned, modeling your tables in accordance would be optimal.